# Propositional Logic- Resolution Rule

Tags: logic

I'm currently taking an Artificial Intelligence class and we recently covered the topic of logical agents.  This is the solution to a question asked about using the resolution inference algorithm:

[Resolution Inference Algorithm Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx8PC.png)

What happens to the (A or B or C) clause at the beginning of the KB?  My teacher claims it is not needed because of the resolution rule.  What makes this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is simply just not needed. As an exercise, try to show:

$(D\vee \neg A)\wedge(\neg B \vee C \vee \neg D)\wedge (C\Rightarrow A)\wedge (D\Rightarrow B)\models \neg C\vee B$,

i.e KB with $(A\vee B \vee C)$ removed, lets call it K.

You then start with negating $\neg C \vee B$ in your resolution and continue to break everything down into atoms and negated atoms.

You will see that your calculations are the same as in the solution, and you will get to a contradiction. So you have $K\models \neg C\vee B$.

As you have probably experienced, these resolutions can be branched, when you need to check for e.g. $P_1\vee P_2$. As soon as you get to a contradiction in such a branch, you can terminate it. But in some cases you could get to a contradiction even before you start your 'branching', well then you can terminate the whole thing. You could say, that this is why $(A\vee B \vee C)$ is never used here.

When proving that $P_1\wedge P_2 \wedge ... \wedge P_n \Rightarrow Q$ by contradiction, like in your example, what you are doing is checking whether you could have that $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ are all true but $Q$ false or not. If you could have that $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ are all true but $Q$ false, then obviously you do not have that $P_1\wedge P_2 \wedge ... \wedge P_n\Rightarrow Q$. In such a case, you would arrive at a counter example. In this case you arrive at a contradiction, meaning that you cannot have that $Q$ is false ($\neg Q$ is true) while all of $P_1,...,P_n$ are true. This means that, given that the premises $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ are all true, then $Q$ is true. So the given statement is correct.

I hope this helps, get back to me if you need more help.

Comment: So let me see if I understand this: Negating the clause in my resolution gives us $C∧¬B$.  Once we start resolving clauses, if we get to a null set, that means that a contradiction exists, correct?  That means that our knowledge base does not entail $¬C∨B$.  Because we get a null set without the use of $(A∨B∨C)$ or $(¬B∨C∨¬D)$, we do not need them to prove this entailment wrong.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: I am really sorry, I have updated my answer. I mixed up the symbols, please read it again. You negate your conclusion $Q=C \wedge \neg B$ to see if it is possible to have that $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ are all true and Q false. If this is impossible, i.e that you run into a contradiction, then it means that Q is always true given that the premises $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ are all true, which means that $P_1,P_2,...,P_n\Rightarrow Q$.

Comment: So again, to be clear, you have (by contradiction) proved that the statement $KB\models \neg C\vee B$ is True. I am sorry if my original answer confused you. I have edited my answer to include a further explanation to why you negate $\neg C\vee B$. And, in short, $(A\vee B \vee C)$ is never used because you arrive at a contradiction 'higher up' in the tree that you are building using the resolution method (the branching would have taken place after the contradiction but there's no need to continue).

Comment: So by contradiction, the null set proves that you cannot have $¬Q$ given KB, meaning $KB⊨Q$ is true.  So if the set were not null, then contradiction proves that KB does not entail Q?

Comment: I am not sure about your terminology here but I think you are on the right track yes. I think you mean that you arrive at an empty set for the valuation, i.e there is no valuation that would make $P_1,P_2,...,P_n,\neg Q$, true at the same time. So yes, this means that $\neg Q$ is always false under these circumstances (i.e $Q$ true). This can also be stated in terms of consistency. $\{P_1,P_2,...,\neg Q\}$ is inconsistent (contains a contradiction) $\Leftrightarrow$ $P_1,P_2,...,P_n \Rightarrow Q$.

Comment: The statement "...if the set were not null..." would mean that: if you had found a valuation (a counter example) for which $P_1,P_2,...,P_n,\neg Q$ are all simultaneously true, then this **counter example** would have proven that $KB$ does not entail $Q$ yes.